# Mongoose JS relationships

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I'm making an express app that has a user model and a post model. The users have many posts and each post belongs to a user. Here are the models

user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
  _id : Number,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  admin: Boolean,
  posts: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

post.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var postSchema = new Schema({
  title: 'string',
  content: 'string',
  _author: {
    type: Number,
    ref: 'User'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

First of all I'm not sure if that is the best way to associate the two models so that post belongs to user but that is what it looked like in the mongoose documentation here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Now what I want to do is when I hit this route

```
router.post('/', function(req, res){
  var post = new Post(req.body);


  console.log(author.posts);

  post.save(function(err){
    if (err){
      return res.send(err);
    }

    res.send({message: 'Post added!'});
  });
});
```

I want the post to be inserted into the user post array. I have been looking through the documentation and believe that the populate method is the way to do this but I can't seem to figure out how to use it and if it actually inserts that post into the authors post array.

I tried this but it didn't seem to do what I wanted

```
Post.findOne({
    title: "The nip"
  })
  .populate('_author')
  .exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('The creator is %s', post._author.username);
  });
```

Any advice on how to get the created post into its authors posts array would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just need a little clarification. I see you trying to `save` a post and also trying to `findOne` a post. Which are you having issues with? `.populate` is only for lookups to serve, not write.

Comment: I also see that you are overriding `_id` in `User` with type `Number`. Why not keep it an `ObjectId`? That very well could be a nuance of Mongoose as you are using `.populate()` correctly

Comment: @Rob I'm trying to save the post and have it associated with a user, I just don't really know what I'm doing with populate yet

Answer (score 2):

I think the mongoose-y way to do this would be with the pre/post middleware. For example, when saving a post you could configure mongoose to automatically keep the user collection in sync like so:

**post.js**

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');

postSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    // Don't do anything unless this is a new Post being created
    // If a Post's author can be changed you would also need to check for that here
    if (!this.isNew) {
        return next();
    }

    User.update({_id: this._author}, {
        $push: {posts: this._id}
    })
    .then(function() {
        next();
    })
    .then(null, function(err) {
        // Whoops! Something broke. You may want to abort this update.
        next(err);
    });
});
```

You can also set up a similar `postSchema.post('remove', ...)` middleware to do cascade deletions.

A few things to note:

1) Calling `mongoose.model` with just one argument like I am above will load the model instead of defining it. Use this to have models reference each other. If you were to use node `module.exports` you could get cyclic dependencies.

2) Follow @Rob's advice about ObjectId. Don't change your id to Number unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the pre-hooks don't run on `.update()`. You would have to pull the Post document into memory and then save it for this to run in the future (doesn't seem to matter in this case)

Comment: ^Good point @cdbajorin, I should clarify that with Mongoose 4 you can set up hooks for `update` and `findAndUpdate` events, eg `postSchema.pre('update')`  More detail: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

Comment: Neat! I haven't sifted through 4 yet

Answer (score 2):

`populate()` doesn't save anything. It is read-based functionality that searches for the `_id` you are populating and appends it to the mongoose document that you just queried for. All this does is save you a a second query to find the user. Nothing is actually being saved.

In regards to design, I wouldn't even bother having the posts array on the user since it has the potential to grow infinitely. In a practical application, you will already have either the user or the post in memory at any given time, so you will already have their `objectId` on hand (as Rob said, don't use `Number`). If you have the user, you can find their posts:

`Post.find({_author: author._id}, callback)`

similarly if you have the post, you can find the user:

`User.findOne({_id: post._author}, callback)`

If you don't have either of them on hand and your application is regularly searching for posts by an author's username, you can add that to the post schema and send it in your save request. This way you can make searching for posts by author easy. Switch the post schema to:

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    _author: {
        _id: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        username: String
    }
});
```

and your query would be:

```
Post.find({"_author.username", username}, callback)
```

It's perfectly OK to repeat data. Applications typically read more than they write, so putting a bit more effort into writing to save time on reading is worth it.

Comment: Not storing a post array on User objects is definitely a viable and simple alternative. Also, to keep your "find all posts for a user" query speedy you should probably index the ref property, eg: `_id: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', index: true}`

Comment: Alright I'll switch things around thanks for the help!